# Rails routes for models with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ancestry

I have a model Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :items, :through => :item_categories
  has_ancestry
end
```

and model Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :item_categories, :uniq => true
end
```

I use this gem - https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

So, URLs on site can be:

```
/category-slug/ - "categories#show"
/category-slug/subcategory-slug
/category-slug/subcategory-slug/subsubcategory-slug
/category-slug/item-slug - "items#show"
/category-slug/subcategory-slug/item-slug
/category-slug/subcategory-slug/subsubcategory-slug/item-slug
```

how will look like routes for this urls? And is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the problem like this:

```
/category1/ - "categories#show"
/category1/category2
/category1/category2/category3
/category1/item - "items#show"
/category1/category2/item
/category1/category2/category3/item-slug
```

I would solve this by the following routes:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :categroies
  resources :items
end
```

This gives:

```
category_categroie GET /categories/:category_id/categroies/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categroies"}
     category_item GET /categories/:category_id/items/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items"}
          category GET /categories/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
```

This solves the six problems as:

```
/categories/1
/categories/1/categories/2
/categories/2/categories/3
/categories/1/item/4
/categories/2/item/5
/categories/3/item/6
```

Maybe you can get your program to work with this solution.